# connecting api controller with service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use an api controller - I am connecting it to a service layer to return results and having some trouble with the set up. This is what i have:

**Service**

```
public IEnumerable<RoleUser> GetUsers(int sectionID)
{
    var _role = DataConnection.GetRole<RoleUser>(sectionID, r => new RoleUser
    {
        Name = RoleColumnMap.Name(r),
        Email = RoleColumnMap.Email(r)
    }, resultsPerPage: 20, pageNumber: 1);
    return _role;
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class RoleView
{
    public RoleView()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<RoleUser>();
    }
    public ICollection<RoleUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class RoleUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Api Controller**
Should i be connecting the RoleUser or to the RoleView and how can i set my data in here to get from the service.

```
public class RoleApiController : ApiController
{
    public RoleUser GetRoleUser(int sectionID)
    {
        if (sectionID != null)
        {
            return new RoleUser
            {
               Name = ,
               Email = 
            };
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
Name: <span id="name"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Email: <span id="email"></span>
</div>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    getRoleUser(9, function (roleUser) {
        $("#name").html(roleUser.Name);
        $("#email").html(roleUser.Email);
    });
    function getRoleUser(id, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/RoleUser",
            data: { id: id },
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            statusCod: {
                200: function (roleUser) { callback(roleUser); },
                404: function () { alter("Not Found!"); }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having?

Comment: @jrummell setting the api controller so it gets the name and email infro from the service layer - api controller above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add a field for your service class in your controller:

```
public class RoleApiController : ApiController
{
    private RoleService _roleService = new RoleService();

    public RoleUser GetRoleUser(int sectionID)
    {
        if (sectionID != null)
        {
            return _roleService.GetUsers(sectionID);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

Comment: now i am getting the error `cannot implicitly convert type system.collections...RoleUser to RoleView` - missing a cast?

Comment: Now that you mention it, the `GetUsers()` method returns a collection, but your Action returns a single user. What is the relationship between `sectionID` and `RoleUser`? Are there many roles per `sectionID`? If so, you'll have to revise your service layer.

Comment: I think that i should use `RoleView` instead of `RoleUser`?