# Cannot implicitly convert type - missing cast - models.views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble building this code - I have an api controller which gets its data from the service layer via the models and this is what i have:

**api controller**

```
public class RoleApiController : ApiController
{
    private RoleService _roleService = new RoleService();

    public RoleUser GetRoleUser(int sectionID)
    {
        if (sectionID != null)
        {
            return _roleService.GetUsers(sectionID);
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public partial class RoleView
{
    public RoleView()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<RoleUser>();
    }
    public ICollection<RoleUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class RoleUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<...RoleUser> to RoleUser. An explicit conversion exists(missing a cast?)

for this line: `return _roleService.GetUsers(sectionID);`

**JavaScript**

```
<div>
Name: <span id="name"></span>
</div>
<div>
    Email: <span id="email"></span>
</div>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript">
    getRoleUser(9, function (roleUser) {
        $("#name").html(roleUser.Name);
        $("#email").html(roleUser.Email);
    });
    function getRoleUser(id, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/RoleUser",
            data: { id: id },
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            statusCod: {
                200: function (roleUser) { callback(roleUser); },
                404: function () { alter("Not Found!"); }
            }
success: function(result){
                result.each(function())
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [connecting api controller with service layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689989/connecting-api-controller-with-service-layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm your returning a collection of users when you should be returning just one?  I can't really tell whether you actually want a collection or not from the code you've shown, but that is your issue.

This will let your code compile, but may not be the solution you want:

```
return _roleService.GetUsers(sectionID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks that helped compile but now i realized that it is not showing any results where there should be. as for what i want to return - i would like to return a collection so would i have change my code in the service?

Comment: You should change the return type of your `Controller` from RoleUser to IEnumerable<RoleUser> and remove the .FirstOrDefault() I added in my answer if you want the Controller action to return a collection.

Comment: thanks that took care of that - now i think there might be an issue with the javascript in displaying the information

Comment: well you likely coded the javascript expecting a single object back instead of a list.  you probably need to do a `result.each(function(index, element) {});` in the ajax success function.

Comment: i added my javascript above if you can take a look and share your advice. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: To be honest you are getting beyond the scope of my knowledge.  I've never returned an actual type across an ajax call, only primitive types and json.  I would suggest that you probably want to either use a list or table to display the users.  in the success function you'll want to .empty() the table or list and then for each element in the result you'll want to .append('some html here') to the table/list to display the users.

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration says it returns RoleUser (singular) while your method would hint it returns a collection.  So either you need to fix the method to return a list or return only a single result from your GetUsers method.